# Merge array with same keys, array_merge_recursive doesn't work as expected

Tags: php, arrays, merge, array-merge

I've two arrays with ids as key and some fields and I would like to merge them but I don't understand why it doesn't work, here is my example code:

```
$Podcasts1 = array("1234" => array('title' => "myTitle", "type" => "myType"));
$Podcast2 = array("1234" => array("content" => "myContent"));
$podcasts = array_merge_recursive($Podcasts1, $Podcast2);
var_dump($Podcasts1, $Podcast2, $podcasts);
```

There is the result:

```
array:1 [▼
  1234 => array:2 [▼
    "title" => "myTitle"
    "type" => "myType"
  ]
]
array:1 [▼
  1234 => array:1 [▼
    "content" => "myContent"
  ]
]
array:2 [▼
  0 => array:2 [▼
    "title" => "myTitle"
    "type" => "myType"
  ]
  1 => array:1 [▼
    "content" => "myContent"
  ]
]
```

And there is the result I woulk like to have:

```
array:[
1234 => array(
        "title" => "myTitle"
        "type" => "myType"
        "content" => "myContent")
]
```

I don't understand why the code given on PHP.net work and mine doesn't

Code:

```
$ar1 = array("color" => array("favorite" => "red"), 5);
$ar2 = array(10, "color" => array("favorite" => "green", "blue"));
$result = array_merge_recursive($ar1, $ar2);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [color] => Array
        (
            [favorite] => Array
                (
                    [0] => red
                    [1] => green
                )

            [0] => blue
        )

    [0] => 5
    [1] => 10
)
```

Comment: if the keys are numeric it will append the value instead of merging it into one array

Comment: I will use "id_124" as key, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the key 1234 to string like

```
 $Podcasts1 = array('a' => array('title' => "myTitle", "type" => "myType"));
 $Podcast2 = array('a' => array("content" => "myContent"));
 $podcasts = array_merge_recursive($Podcasts1, $Podcast2);
 var_dump($Podcasts1, $Podcast2, $podcasts);
```

array_merge_recursive works on string keys.

Comment: Thanks ! It's working and it's explain why my code doesn't work but I need theses ids to identify when it's the same podcast in both arrays..
Is there no solution except adding a string to the begining of the id (like "a124" wich is bad way to do what I want to do...)

Comment: if you are using array_merge_recursive then you have to use string keys like id_1234.

Answer (score 0):

It wont work for numeric key as function description says

If the input arrays have the same string keys, then the values for these keys are merged together into an array, and this is done recursively, so that if one of the values is an array itself, the function will merge it with a corresponding entry in another array too. If, however, the arrays have the same numeric key, the later value will not overwrite the original value, but will be appended.

[Ref Link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php)